# How to round values to your expectations

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input values to below Python program:

20
21
22

Expected Output:

32

```
import math
n_stu_grp1 = abs(int(input()))
n_stu_grp2 = abs(int(input()))
n_stu_grp3 = abs(int(input()))
n_desk = (n_stu_grp1 + n_stu_grp2 + n_stu_grp3) / 2
print(n_desk)
```

My code as mentioned above generates output as 31.5, i tried also using math.ceil(n_desk) but it gives me the same result ? Pls advise how we can get result as 32

Hi Friends, pls refer the code which i tried using math.ciel:

```
import math
n_stu_grp1 = abs(int(input()))
n_stu_grp2 = abs(int(input()))
n_stu_grp3 = abs(int(input()))
n_desk = (n_stu_grp1 + n_stu_grp2 + n_stu_grp3) / 2
n_desk_l = math.ceil(n_desk)
print(n_desk_l)
```

the above mentioned code is against a coding prolem as mentioned below :

> A school has decided to create three new math groups and equip three
> classrooms for them with new desks. At most two students may sit at any
> desk. The number of students in each of the three groups is known. Output the smallest number of desks to be purchased.
> Each group will sit in its own classroom.
>
> Input data format:
>
> The program receives the input of three non-negative integers: the number of students in each of the three classes (the numbers do not exceed 1000).
>
> For ex: 20 21 22

Problem : As per above problem statement and as per my understanding my code is right which i have written using `math.ceil`. What are your thoughts my friends?
The issue is that my program is failing some random tests for ex when i give input `17,22 and 23` it fails the test of the coding platform ? pls advice

Comment: `print(math.ceil(n_desk))` should work. Show what you actually tried in the script.

Comment: have you tried the round() function

Comment: @Barmar : Hi Barmar, i wrote the code as mentioned below

Comment: @Bryan Deng : Yes i tried but is not helping much, Pls refer the updated problem statement which i have mentioned, Thanks.

Comment: The problem is your formula, not the rounding. You need to divide each class by 2, rounding up, then total them, not total all the classes first.

Comment: In your failing example you need 9+11+12=32 desks, but you're calculating 31.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function round. It's inputs are round(*number*, *digits*).

So for you I'd do

```
n_desk = round((n_stu_grp1 + n_stu_grp2 + n_stu_grp3) / 3), 0)
print(n_desk)
```

Comment: Thanks @TheFrator for sharing your approach but my problem is not resolved yet, pls refer the updated problem statement i have shared against which i have written this code , also i have shared my updated code, Pls have a look on the same, any advice on the same will be helpful..Thanks

Comment: This may round down instead of up.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to resolve the above problem using below code, Thanks to all for your inputs.

```
    import math
    n_stu_grp1 = abs(int(input()))
    n_stu_grp2 = abs(int(input()))
    n_stu_grp3 = abs(int(input()))
    n_desk_grp1 = math.ceil(n_stu_grp1 / 2)
    n_desk_grp2 = math.ceil(n_stu_grp2 / 2)
    n_desk_grp3 = math.ceil(n_stu_grp3 / 2)
    n_desk = n_desk_grp1 + n_desk_grp2 + n_desk_grp3
    print(n_desk)
```